# Representations of set of angles(radians) like as set of natural numbers $~ \mathbb{N} ~$ , set of real numbers$~ \mathbb{R} ~$

Tags: notation

$$n\in\mathbb{N}~~\leftarrow~~n~~\text{takes a value of natural number.}$$

I've been searhing the(official)symbol of set which includes elements of radian(angular)values.

I wonder if such symbol(I may prefer the representation by one character(letter))exist as like below one.

$$\theta_{}\in\mathbb{X}~~\leftarrow~~\theta_{}~~~\text{takes a value of radian}$$

Is there?

Comment: $[0,2\pi]$ is a candidate

Comment: The trig functions sine and cosine are defined for all real $x$, and $x$ is given in radian measure, so the set you are asking about is just ${\bf R}$, the set of reals. [Indeed, those functions are defined for all complex arguments, too, so you could use ${\bf C}$.]

Comment: Any thoughts on the suggestions you have received, electrical?

Comment: I think your commentary of $~\theta\in\mathbb{R}~$ is best for me so far.

Answer (score 1):

I would use $[0, 2\pi)$ and then express $\theta$ actually as "$\frac{\theta}{1\, \operatorname{rad}} \mod 2\pi$".